# How to recover organic position in Google results after server down?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, disaster-recovery

I have several sites that were doing quite well in terms of organic SEO rankings.  I have the important sites setup in Google's Webmaster tools.

Long story short, the system was down for about two weeks.  Now in AdSense and Analytics, I am seeing that the page views are SLOWLY increasing. and I would like to know if there is anything I can do now to try to expedite the process of regaining those positions.

Since there were several errors from that server, is it possible that Google will now rank any site from that IP address lower due to those two weeks of errors?  Is this something that I just have to let ride out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to re-submit your sitemaps, and also view the page as Google bot in webmaster tools. Other than that there isn't much you can do. Wait for Google to re-index your sites where they were. Continue adding content as you did before the server was down and be patient. Just as Google will remove your site from it's index when infected with Malware or display the notice on the SERP's once you clean your site you can simply wait and you'll be re-included as Google bot crawls you.